# Stop exim retrying failed emails

Tags: email, cpanel, mail-server, exim, email-bounces

My Webserver has been denied from Yahoo! and every time an email is sent to a Yahoo! server, it fails and replies with:

```
Connecting to mta7.am0.yahoodns.net [66.94.238.147]:25 ... connected
  SMTP<< 421 4.7.1 [TS03] All messages from 108.xx.xxx.xx will be permanently deferred; Retrying will NOT succeed. See http://postmaster.yahoo.com/421-ts03.html
```

It seems that Exim will continuously try and try again to deliver these bounced emails.

What can I do to disable this feature?

Answer (score 0):

This error message indicates there is high volume of messages from your IP address to yahoo, which mean there is spamming going on your server. Check the server and stop the spamming. Yahoo usually removes the block after 48 hours after the spamming is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, high volume is not always spam: I decided to "import" my former Emails from a self hosted server to yahoo using fetchmail + procmail to forward it to Yahoo. The mecanism is about to use an MTA for the forward. This is a massive input from my Exim to Yahoo.